# troubleshoot Android Application

Tags: android

After I launch my app, I see my startup activity with the title bar and a blank screen.  After a long delay (about 8 seconds), I finally see my splash screen.

This behavior is inconsistent....it can be a delay from 2 seconds (the time I specified in the code) to 8 seconds.

Can someone  suggest a plan to diagnose the issue?  What tools are available to use and what resources should I be looking at?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is often the case if you are loading a lot of resources into memory, if you could show some of your code it would be useful.

I have found that some people that have used soundpool to load all the sounds in their app in the oncreate, however this is slow and takes up lots of memory (Should use create a mediaplayer instance and give it sounds while your app is running)

Comment: I definitely have a lot of resources.  I was just wondering why the delay is not consistent....why is it fast one time and slow the next.  I am not using soundpool and loading all the sounds in the oncreate.

Comment: Maybe the resources are still in memory from last time, or there you are waiting for garbage collection. You mention your already using a splashscreen, if you make sure your not loading the resources before it is created and displayed then it should appear very quickly. I'd check where you are loading resources and consider if there is a more sensible place to put them.

Answer (score 0):

look into the logfile.
Open a command line console and go to the tools directory of the Android SDK and type

```
adb shell logcat
```

Or if you develop with Eclipse, there's also a logfile output there, switch to the DDMS perspective, there you see a 'logcat' tab.

Comment: Thanks.  I already use LogCat in Eclipse, but I was looking for some guidance on what to look for.  Maybe I can start with the warnings and errors in LogCat.

Comment: Are the title bar and blank screen you described above part of your application? Or are you referring to the general system title bar in Android?
Are you developing on emulator or on a real device? Does the delay only happen when you launch the app from within Eclipse, or also when you start the app directly on your emulator/device from the home screen / app icon?
Check the log for the messages that are coming up after the 'installing apk' message in the log.